# Asp.net Web API Serializing List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I am using Asp.net Web Api and i am trying to return a list of DTO objects.

This is what i have:

```
// Wrapper
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "get-applications-result")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "get-applications-result")]
public class GetApplicationsResult : List<ApplicationDTO>
{

}

// DTO object
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "application")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", ElementName = "application")]
public class ApplicationDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "application-name")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "application-name")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```

In `Global.asax` i set

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

However, when i return the response from server to the client, it returns it like this:

```
<get-applications-result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ApplicationDTO>
        <application-name>Application name</application-name>
    </ApplicationDTO>
</get-applications-result>
```

How can i make the `<ApplicationDTO/>` to be rendered as `<application/>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [XmlTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx) on the ApplicationDTO class instead of the [XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "application")]
[XmlType(TypeName = "application")]
public class ApplicationDTO
{
    [DataMember(Name = "application-name")]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "application-name")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
}
```